# Masonry's responsive layout has large gutters on wider page sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, masonry

I've got an image gallery style section on my website. I'm using Masonry for the image layout. For the most part, it looks good.

[image]

However, when expanding the page to a larger resolutions, the gutter between the first 2 columns will sometimes widen as well.

Like so:

[image]

This is not what I want. Ideally I'd want small margins between images at all times, something like a pinterest layout. Help?

Relevant code is as follows:

**js:**

```
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  percentPosition: true,
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  gutter: 5,
});
// layout Isotope after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.masonry();
});
```

**css:**

```
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: calc(33.3333% - 5px);
}
.grid-item {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.grid-item img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.grid-item:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
    filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;    
}
```

**HTML/Blade (using laravel)**

```
<h3>Latest uploads</h3>
@if (count($images) == 0)
<p>This artist does not have any images currently uploaded.</p> 
@else
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  @foreach ($images as $image)  
  <div class="grid-item featuredTextContainer"">
    <a href="{{ route('image.get', ['username' => $user->username, 'URLtitle' => $image->url_title]) }}"><img src="{{ url($image->medium_path) }}"></a>
    <span class="featuredArtistName">{{ $image->title }}</span>
  </div>
 @endforeach
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: You're right! Would there be a way to make it so a 4th column is placed instead of expanding the images further?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your images have reached their native resolution and are no longer expanding to fit the cells. I'm guessing you have some CSS to make them responsive, something like `max-width: 100%;`. In the case of `max-width: 100%;` we're saying the image can take up to but not more space than its container will allow. If the image has a larger width than the parent, the image is scaled down. If the image has a smaller width than the parent, the image is left alone as it's no longer greater than or equal to the parent's width.

Either up the size of your source images or allow them to expand beyond their native size (pixelation will occur).

My answers do not include/use Masonry as I do not see this as a Masonry issue but rather a CSS and image implementation issue.

Example of what I believe is happening in your situation.

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 25px auto;
}
.container > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #c00;
  overflow: hidden; /* clearfix */
}
.container img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x500/ccc">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x500/ccc">
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Example 1 Fix - Allow Image to expand beyond native size

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 25px auto;
}
.container > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #c00;
  overflow: hidden; /* clearfix */
}
.container img {
  display: block;
  /* max-width: 100%; */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x500/ccc">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x500/ccc">
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Example 2 Fix - Larger Images

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 25px auto;
}
.container > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #c00;
  overflow: hidden; /* clearfix */
}
.container img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x2000/ccc">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x2000/ccc">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would there be a way to, instead of expanding the images further, simply add more columns as the page is expanded? Something like this: http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/example/flex-grid.html (this uses freewall and not masonry)

Comment: Maybe, I'm aware of what Masonry is/does but not familiar with any of the specifics. I would check the documentation as it sounds like you want to set a max width for your columns. Either of those libraries may or may not have an option for adding columns based on column width and the amount of available space.

Comment: From a very quick peek at [Masonry Layout](http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html) it looks like percentage widths won't work for you and you'll have to use set widths for `.grid-item`.